# recovering wallet

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat, windows, cross-chain-recovery

0

I am not exactly sure what I need to do and I do not want to accidentally overwrite my disk. I may have already done so.

After searching my web history I have found the BTC address that my BTC is on but obviously I can't access my wallet. Before I formatted my hard drives I used easeus disk clone and I cloned it on 2, maybe 3, separate hard drives. But it didn't seem to work properly. I have scanned those drives and found what I believe is the file that holds my wallet but whenever I copy/paste my wallet.dat file, Bitcoin Core does not load up and I am not even sure if that's the right file anyways. I have a lot of money in that wallet and I really need to get it back.

Comment: nobody has helped me or even answered in 2 months so I re-posted ...should I not have?

Comment: How to recover my wallet questions are asked probably weekly on this site so if the other answers didn't help you, you should explain what you've tried

Comment: Please do not repost the same question but rather seek to improve the original question by adding more background information, answering questions for clarification, and telling what you've tried since.